# Avoiding Duplicate API calls in shared custom hook between React components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have written custom hook which uses `useEffect` hook to call an API. This custom hook is shared between two Components. Both the components are rendered on the same page. Now the problem is, the API is getting called twice, once each component gets rendered.

Both the components need to use the response from the API call. What can be done to avoid this duplicate API call ? Or is there any other way same can be achieved ?

Comment: You need to separate the business logic from the view logic.
Instead call that hook in the didComponentUpdate of their parent and pass the data to both of them as props.

Comment: Since you have not shared the code, I can only suggest trying to fetch the response in your parent and pass the response of API as a prop to your children. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes that's what I did. I fetched the response in parent and passed as props in both the components. Thanks!